# Mixed chart type - Angular ChartJS

Tags: angular-chart

I am trying to create a mixed chart with the angular plugin instead of plain javascript. For that, I am using this library http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

In plain javascript it is created with something similar to this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: "Visitor",
        data: [200, 185, 590, 621, 250, 400, 95],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: '#71B37C',
        borderColor: '#71B37C',
        hoverBackgroundColor: '#71B37C',
        hoverBorderColor: '#71B37C',
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
      },
      {
        label: "Sales",
        type:'line',
        data: [51, 65, 40, 49, 60, 37, 40],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#EC932F',
        backgroundColor: '#EC932F',
        pointBorderColor: '#EC932F',
        pointBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#EC932F',
        pointHoverBorderColor: '#EC932F',
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label'
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          labels: {
            show: true,
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: "linear",
          display: true,
          position: "left",
          id: "y-axis-1",
          gridLines:{
            display: false
          },
          labels: {
            show: true,
          }
        },
        {
          type: "linear",
          display: true,
          position: "right",
          id: "y-axis-2",
          gridLines: {
            display: false
          },
          labels: {
            show:true,
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

It can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/TvY5tz?p=preview

I have tried tons of ways to do the same thing with angular-chart but I have been unable to do so. Has anyone been able to create any mixed chart type with the library? If so, please share any example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible right now, there is an open issue to track this: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/336

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible with 1.0.0-alpha8, See [here on github](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#mixed)